# Why doesn't my jQuery selector notice when I remove a class?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, removeclass

I have an element contained in a parent element with the class `active`, like so:

```
<div class="active">
    <div class="button"></div>
</div>
```

I have jQuery set up to handle a click on my `button` div, but only if that div is contained by an `active` parent, like so:

```
$('.active .button').click(function(){
    alert('Button clicked!');
});
```

I use jQuery to remove the `active` class from the parent, and even after removing the class, the alert still pops up when I click on the button.  This seems very unusual, since the button no longer meets the selector's criteria.  It happens in Chrome, Firefox, and IE, so it seems to be the intentional behavior.  Am I missing something? or is there at least an easy way to workaround this?

Here's a simple JSFiddle example for testing purposes: http://jsfiddle.net/KjuDy/.  Click on a box in the top row.  This pops up an alert and removes the `active` class, as expected.  The problem happens when you click a box in the top row even after the `active` class is gone.  I would expect the alert to not pop up, but it still does.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The handlers are assigned one time based on the results found in the selector when it runs (I'm guessing on DOM ready).

Modifying the class of those elements afterward doesn't affect the handlers that were bound.

If you want it to be more dynamic, place [a `.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) handler instead on an ancestor of the elements,

```
$('#someContainer').delegate('.active .button','click',function(){
    alert('Button clicked!');
});
```

If the only container that encompasses all the elements is the `<body>`, then use that:

```
$('body').delegate('.active .button','click',function(){
    alert('Button clicked!');
});
```

**Your example, updated:** http://jsfiddle.net/KjuDy/1/

Comment: Thanks! This worked perfectly not only in the simplified jsfiddle example, but also in my real project.  I have a little reading to do so I actually understand what's going on here, but at least my project is functional for the time being.

Comment: @mlms13: To give a brief overview, the `.delegate()` function uses "event delegation". Many types of on the page "bubble". In other words, if you click the page, then starting with the deepest nested element that was clicked, it will check to see if there's a "click" handler assigned to that element. If so, it invokes it. Then it moves on to that element's parent, and does the same thing, and so on until it reaches the document root. With "event delegation", you're placing the event handler on some parent container. Then a click event that happens inside the container will bubble up to it...

Comment: ...and fire its handler. So the way jQuery's `.delegate()` method works specifically, is that the first argument you pass is the *selector* that will be used to test the element *inside* the container that was clicked. In your case, you're passing `.active .button`. So any element inside the container that when clicked matches that selector, jQuery will fire the handler. That's why clicking a `.button` that descends from `.active` will invoke the handler, but when you remove the `active` class, that same button will no longer do so because it no longer matches the selector. Hope this helps.

Comment: (side note) The way `.live()` works is the same, except that the container is *always* the `document`, which means that it needs to test *every* click on the page against *every* selector it was given. Many people don't know this. That's why I always recommend `.delegate()` since it causes a person to think in terms of which specific container to use instead of blindly using the `document`.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery is binding to DOM elements that match when you first bind the click event.

Look at jQuery [live](http://api.jquery.com/live).